# Является ли это предложение сложным?

Tags: пунктуация

Увидела такую фразу: "язык — это основа национальной памяти(,) и надо его беречь". Честно говоря, не соображу: нужна тут запятая или нет?

Answer (score 3):

Нужна, предложение сложное: первое двусоставное, второе односоставное безличное.